# What is the difference between Queenie's enchantment and the Imperius Curse?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, the-crimes-of-grindelwald

In *Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald* when we first meet Queenie and Jacob, the witch has him placed under a powerful enchantment that makes Jacob more susceptible to her suggestions. How different is that enchantment from the Imperius Curse and why isn't that enchantment regulated by the Ministries of Magic?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any suggestion that Queenie's enchantment can make him do anything that he doesn't already want to, if his inhibitions were lowered

Comment: @Valorum In fact it just appears to put him in a daze.

Answer (score 8):

Queenie's enchantment just appears to put Jacob in a very strong daze. So much so that he doesn't know what he is doing and is sort of being looked after like he's a child.

> **SCENE 36**
>   **INT. NEWT’S SITTING ROOM—FIVE MINUTES LATER—NIGHT**
>
> [...]
>
> *A silence. Then NEWT starts to notice JACOB’S state: Eating sloppily, he hums to himself, then tries to drink the salt. QUEENIE takes it and puts his glass in his hand, trying to cover.*
>
> **QUEENIE:** Anyway... We’re real excited to be here, Newt. This is a—well, it’s a special trip for us. You see, Jacob and I, we’re getting married.
>
> *She shows him her engagement ring. JACOB tries to toast the moment and pours beer all over his ear.*
>
> **JACOB:** I’m marrying Jacob!
>
> *Now sure he knows what’s going on, NEWT glares at QUEENIE.*
>
> <sub>*Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald - The Original Screenplay*</sub>

In fact Queenie herself doesn't appear to have too much control over what Jacob does and has to ask him various times to hand over the broken vase.

> **SCENE 35**
>   **INT. NEWT’S SITTING ROOM—NIGHT**
>
> [...]
>
> **QUEENIE:** If you could just give it to me... Just give it to me, sweetie. Just give it to me. *(whispering)* If you could just give this to me, sweetheart. Oh!
>
> **JACOB:** *(looking at NEWT)* He doesn’t care. Hold it.
>
> <sub>*Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald - The Original Screenplay*</sub>

Lastly, the enchantment would appear to be some sort of Love Potion sort of enchantment, potentially an Entrancing Enchantment as Jacob sees in a pink and hazy fashion and Entrancing Enhancements are known to be similar in colour.

> **SCENE 36**
>   **INT. NEWT’S SITTING ROOM—FIVE MINUTES LATER—NIGHT**
>
> [...]
>
> *JACOB’S POV—pink and hazy, as though happily drunk.*
>
> <sub>*Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald - The Original Screenplay*</sub>

Of course this is then different to the Imperius Curse as that puts the person under complete control. Whereas this enchantment only seems to make the person more susceptible to being controlled, though even then it's controlling effects are very limited.

Comment: Not too different from a lasting confundus charm, which isn't illegal